# Patsy formula when variable has a hypthen

Tags: python, statsmodels, patsy

I am trying to use the statsmodel linear regression functions with formulas. My sample data is coming from a Pandas data frame. I am having a slight problem with column names within the formula.  Due to the downstream processes, I have hyphens within my column names. For example:

```
+------+-------+-------+
+ VOLT +  B-NN + B-IDW +
+------+-------+-------+
```

Now, one of the reasons for keeping the hyphen as it allows python to split the string for other analysis, so I have to keep it. As you can see, when I want to regress VOLT with B-NN using `VOLT ~ B-NN`, I encounter a problem as the patsy formula cannot find B.

Is there a way to tell Patsy that *B-NN* is a variable name and not B minus NN?

Thanks.

BJR

Answer (score 10, accepted):

patsy uses `Q` for quoting names, e.g. `Q('B-IDW')`

http://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builtins-reference.html#patsy.builtins.Q

```
my_fit_function("y ~ Q('weight.in.kg')", ...)
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was after, I just was not sure to look for! Works perfectly. Thanks Josef.